# looking for a Gnome panel applet which can open and close the dvd/cd tray

Tags: gnome, panel, applet

I am looking for a Gnome panel applet which can open and close the dvd/cd tray , I am on Ubuntu 11.04 and use Gnome Classic desktop environment.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know any applet capable of triggering the cd tray, but you can add a custom launcher as applet.

1. Choose "Custom Application Launcher" from the "Add to Panel" menu.
2. Set "Type:" to "Application in Terminal"
3. Choose a name.
4. Write `eject -T` in the "Command" field.
5. Click OK and try it.

This should work, but I could not test it, since I do not have a cd drive.

For detailed information about this command, type `man eject` in a terminal.

Comment: This closes the tray if* it is open, I need an applet that can do both, like open the tray if it close or close it if is open?

Comment: Sorry, try an uppercase "T": `eject -T`

Comment: wonder where I can find an icon for it...

Comment: found it... added this icon here: http://openclipart.org/image/250px/svg_to_png/34543/drive-optical.png, looks damn cool :D